# General 400/500 error handling in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have been building a react website and may need support in creating error pages 404, 500 but I am unsure how to get this working - as I have many api services/actions - how would the errorhandler be invoked if an error occurs in any or all services?

I've seen this link on handling granular error pages - https://code-maze.com/react-net-core-error-handling/

The error page I have in place is just a 404 if the routes fail to work with other pages - so its a the bottom of the routes.

so I've made the two pages

```
import NotFound from './components/ErrorPages/NotFound/NotFound';
import InternalServer from './components/ErrorPages/InternalServer/InternalServer';
```

at the bottom of the route

```
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => (<Home/>)} />
        
        <Route path="/500" component={InternalServer} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
```

//actions

```
export const HTTP_404_ERROR = 'HTTP_404_ERROR';
export const HTTP_500_ERROR = 'HTTP_500_ERROR';
export const HTTP_OTHER_ERROR = 'HTTP_OTHER_ERROR';


const execute404Handler = (props) => {
    return {
        type: HTTP_404_ERROR,
        props: props
    }
}
const execute500Handler = (props) => {
    return {
        type: HTTP_500_ERROR,
        props: props
    }
}
const executeOtherErrorHandler = (error) => {
    return {
        type: HTTP_OTHER_ERROR,
        error: error
    }
}
export const handleHTTPError = (error, props) => {
    if (error.response.status === 404) {
        return execute404Handler(props);
    }
    else if (error.response.status === 500) {
        return execute500Handler(props);
    }
    else {
        return executeOtherErrorHandler(error);
    }
}
```

//reducer

```
import { HTTP_404_ERROR, HTTP_500_ERROR, HTTP_OTHER_ERROR } from '../actions/errorHandlerActions';

const initialState = {
    data: "",
    showErrorModal: false,
    errorMessage: ""
}
const execute404 = (state, action) => {
    action.props.history.push('/404');
    return { ...state, isError: true };
}
const execute500 = (state, action) => {
    action.props.history.push('/500');
    return { ...state, isError: true };
}
const executeOtherError = (state, action) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        showErrorModal: true,
        errorMessage: action.error.response.data
    };
}

export function errorHandlerReducer (state = initialState, {type, payload} = {}) {
  switch (type) {
    case HTTP_404_ERROR:
        return execute404(state, payload);
    case HTTP_500_ERROR:
        return execute500(state, payload);
    case HTTP_OTHER_ERROR:
        return executeOtherError(state, payload);      
    default:
      return {...state} 
  }
}
```

---

Comment: how do you invoke the correct error page - if you got like 20+ api service calls? -- sometimes in a chain

Answer (score 2):

Keeping this candid, you are introducing a lot of unnecessary complexity into your app that only degrades the [DX](https://developerexperience.io/practices/good-developer-experience) and UX.  When handling data fetching/API errors in React, you should strive to prevent breaking errors from hitting the client. At this same token you should never intentionally push a client to a 500 page - instead gracefully handle the error and display a message.

At the lowest level you should wrap all of your asynchronous request in [try catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) or [Promise.catch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) to prevent request errors from breaking the client.  In the catch, you can handle errors by their status code - gracefully.

```
try {
  await fetchData();
} catch (error) {
 if(error.response.status === 500) {//check the library you use to fetch data for how they responds with error statuses
    ...do something graceful like show a message or call your reducer
 }
}
```

Another circuit breaker you should use is an [error boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) to prevent errors from completely breaking the client.  You can declare it once in the main component and it can be used throughout the app to provide a backup method to gracefully catch and display errors.

Lastly, the only errors that you wouldn't handle are hard errors outside of React, which none of this or your code would reach anyway.

If you do the above, you don't need any of your above code - just catch errors and wrap points of failures in error boundaries.

You would handle 404 errors however, the routing framework you are using suggest. For example, in React Router v5 you would put a [catch all route at the end of our routes](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/no-match) (`<Route path=*">`) that catches all routes that did not match (404) or push the user to a 404 page as the routing frameworks suggest (`router.push('/404')`).

Comment: the client want to handle 500 error pages - in the way I started trying to setup the application.

Comment: You asked for the React way and the above is how you should do handle errors.  I updated the post a little to give a little more clarity.  If you must do it how you have above - I gave an example of how to call your reducer in the try/catch.  But again, you will need to use try/catch and error boundaries or you will have hard errors that break your app - not allowing your reducers to be called.

Comment: I got a lot of services - and some of them are chained - so I've been unsure how to make such a heavy modification - maybe - I could do at the get/put axios level - as I've defined them as common methods

Comment: If every request uses a singleton Axios instance - you can the catch errors there like I showed above.  You should still put a React error boundary at the top level and use it throughout as a failsafe. This would prevent one route or component from breaking the whole app.